# Python and fibonnaci [list] generator

Tags: python, fibonacci

I've been trying to generate a Fibonacci sequence using Python 3. Since I'm totally new to programming I'm using basic tools. Lists in this case, as an exercise.
The problem, I have, is to stop the sequence when I want it to stop.

For example,I need a Fibonacci up to 100 so I wrote this:

```
fib = [1,2]
n = 0
while max(fib) <= 100:
    fib.append(fib[n]+fib[n+1])
    n = n+1

print(fib)
print(max(fib))
print(n)
```

The `print()` statements are for my benefit only, so I would know what is going on.

In return I get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
144
9
```

So everything is working fine except I intended the sequenced to be finished before it passes 100.
Why I have the 144 there then? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because at the time of your last iteration, the last item in `fib` is 89, so it's less than 100. because the condition is still satisfied at that point, it still generates one more.

Comment: You are actually checking if the max of the array is less than 100. When it gets to 89, the max is 89, so the code inside the while function is executed. What you want to do is to append value to the list only of it is less than 100.

Comment: It's faster to replace `max(fib)` with `fib[-1]` because the `fib` list is always sorted und thus the maximum element is always the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, the issue is that your loop will still be executed one more time when `max(fib)` is 89, as it is still less than 100. So, it will generate the 144 before finding a `max(fib)` greater than 100.

While there are certainly other ways to do this, in keeping your general loop structure, you could do this:

```
while fib[n]+fib[n+1] < 100:
    fib.append(fib[n]+fib[n+1])
    n = n+1

>>> fib
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Answer (score 2):

just put an if statement inside your loop.

```
while max(fib) <= 100:
        if(fib[n]+fib[n+1] > 100):
            break
        fib.append(fib[n]+fib[n+1])
        n = n+1
```

What break statements do is, if the breaking condition is met, the program immediately gets out of the loop .

Also your looping condition is a bit inefficient since it has to check for the max value in the list fib on every iteration.

A simpler approach would be like this

```
while (fib[n]+fib[n+1] < 100):
        fib.append(fib[n]+fib[n+1])
        n = n+1
```

This way your code doesn't have to check for the max value on every iteration

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

- The Fibonacci sequence starts with `1, 1, 2, ...`
- You check if the greatest element is less than `100`, rather than checking if the *next* element is less than `100`.

So, the first is obviously easy to correct, just declare `fib` as `[1, 1]`.

As for the second, you could either use a `while True` loop which you then `break` out of if the next element is greater than `100`, or you could have a variable which stores the next and just check that this is less than `100` as the evaluation for the `while`.

So, after this line:

```
fib = [1, 1]
```

You could either use:

```
next = 2
while next <= 100:
    fib.append(next)
    next += fib[-2]
```

or

```
while True:
    next = fib[-2] + fib[-1]
    if next > 100:
        break
    fib.append(next)
```

which both give:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is very simple. You are checking that the biggest number in `fib` is less than or equal to 100, but when you add the last two items together the end value may be larger.

You can fix this by checking the new value before you add it to the list.

Also, in Python you can access the last item the list by doing

```
fib[-1]
```

Therefore you can remove `n` by changing your code to use negative indexes.

Finally, the fibonnacci sequence should start with 1, 1 not 1, 2.

```
fib = [1, 1]

while True:
    n = fib[-1] + fib[-2]
    if n >= 100:
        break
    fib.append(n)

print(fib)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong, what you wanted is wrong.

It generates more than 100 because 89+55 is 144, you wanted the sequence to be less than 100, not their value after adding.

Try to use "if" statement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common mistake to make when you start programming :)

You are testing whether the maximum value in 'fib' is still under 100, and **then** you are adding a new number. So while you test, fib is still [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89] and then 144 gets added inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
while max(fib) <= 100:
```

you want to be checking whether the next number is greater than 100, but you are actually checking if the current largest number in the list is greater than 100.

So, instead of the program saying "144 is larger than 100, lets not add it", it's going "89 is less than 100, lets add 144!"

To fix this, you need to check how large the number you're adding *next* is. You can do this with an `if` statement in your while loop, and having a different variable to hold whether you should quit the loop or not. For example:

```
fib = [1,1]
n = 0
quit = False
while not quit:
  next_num = fib[n]+fib[n+1]
  if next_num <= 100:
    fib.append(next_num)
    n = n+1
  else:
    quit = True

print(fib)
print(max(fib))
print(n)
```

Also, as [Joe Iddon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464950/python-and-fibonnaci-list-generator/49465055#49465055) said, the Fibonacci sequence starts with "1, 1, 2"

Answer (score 0):

So many replies :)

In the end i went with the:

```
while fib[n]+fib[n+1] < 100
fib.append(fib[n]+fib[n+1])
n = n+1
```

which seemed to me to be the simplest (still much to learn)

But I'm glad that there were so many differnt approches shown here. I'll try to remeber them all. Moreover I learned where my logic was wrong and that's good too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this code, If u have any question, I will try explain you every moment

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        a, b = 0, 1
        for _ in range(1, n):
            a, b = b, a + b
        return b

n = int(input("Enter the Fibonacci number: "))
result = fibonacci(n)
print(f"The Fibonacci number number {n} is {result}")
```